# Open Kinect - OpenNI, NITE - Compilation issues

Tags: kinect, openni

I am busy trying to get the kinect working using Ubuntu 15.10. I have installed Libfreenect, OpenNI, NITE as well as SensorKinect.

I am able to run the programs in the OpenNI/Platform/Linux/Bin/x64-Release/ folder, for example Sample-NiUserTracker... However I have so far been unable to compile any of my own code.

I have tried to compile the examples in the Samples folder, for example SimpleViewer.java but I just get the following error:

```
 SimpleViewerApplication.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    private SimpleViewer viewer;
            ^
  symbol:   class SimpleViewer
  location: class SimpleViewerApplication
SimpleViewerApplication.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
        app.viewer = new SimpleViewer();
                         ^ 
symbol:   class SimpleViewer
 location: class SimpleViewerApplication
2 errors
```

I also tried to compile the C++ programs to no avail. Any suggestions on how to get something to compile would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so unfortunately you cannot just naively compile the example programs directly as they need to be linked with a whole bunch of files. One method of compiling without worrying about creating your own makefiles is to edit one of the existing files and go the OpenNI/Platform/Linux/Build and enter make. This will compile the example programs for you. and you can go to OpenNI/Platform/Linux/Bin/x64-Release and run the compile code.

Something that makes all this easier is to install PyOpenNI. Which enables you to code for the Kinect in glorious Python.

You can see full instructions at my github page https://github.com/RobbieJKatz/Kinect.